# Having "WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid" while importing 3D model on THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm try to import a 3D model with GLTFLoader in THREE.js, it work for me when I use models without animation in gltf file, but when I use model that contain animation in gltf file, the waning shows up and the model doesn't show on the scene.

```
/----------------Setups-------------//
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//------------------OrbitControl---------------------//
const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
orbit.update(); 



//------------------3D model---------------------//
const donkeyURL = new URL("../assets/car/scene.gltf", import.meta.url);
const assetsLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath(
      "https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.5.7/"
    );
dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: "js" });
assetsLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
assetsLoader.load(
  donkeyURL.href,
  (gltf) => {
    const model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(model);
    model.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    model.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  },
  undefined,
  function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
);

//------------------Animation---------------------//

function animate() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
```

My model is imported cuz, when I console.log(model) , Ican see the informations of the model,

I've try to set scale or camera position but still... does anyone having this problem?

Comment: Do you see the same error when loading the model in a three.js-based viewer like https://threejs.org/editor/ or https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ ? If so, it would be best to file a bug on three.js and include the glTF file as an attachment.

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly, yes it's work perfectly on both THREE editor and gltf-viewer.  the error olny showup whe I'm load from three.js

Comment: If the model is working in both places, but the error occurs in your code, then we might need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to figure out what's different in your case. It might be worth checking to make sure you're using a recent version of three.js, as well.

Comment: thanks again fior replying,  I've paste my code , and I'm sure that my THREE.js is the recent version 0.162.0

Comment: I maybe find a problem, I'm used WebGL1Renderer insted of WebGLRenderer,
The model shows up when I use WebGLRenderer, what is the difference between both of them?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGL1Renderer)?

Comment: WebGLRenderer uses WebGL 2 if available, or WebGL 1 if not. Some features are not supported in WebGL 1, so perhaps that's the cause here. In three.js r163, support for WebGL 1 is being removed, so I would recommend using WebGLRenderer instead.

Comment: @gre_gor yeah I've cheked!